# Mechanicalsoup freezes with some websites

Tags: python, freeze, mechanicalsoup

I use MechanicalSoup for a custom search engine. When I try to open some websites, MechanicalSoup freezes, up to few hours, and gives an exception only after this delay. Sometimes it works, but it is always very long with some websites ex:

```
import mechanicalsoup
browser = mechanicalsoup.StatefulBrowser()
browser.open('https://www.amd.com')
browser.open('https://www.airfrance.fr')
```

How can I use mechanicalsoup and not have this freeze, or how can I set a short time out (10s max for example), in order to avoid waiting hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MechanicalSoup API is a thin wrapper around the Requests library, which accepts a `timeout` argument in the relevant function calls (see https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/#timeouts).

Therefore, you can set a 10 second timeout in MechanicalSoup by adding `timeout=10`, e.g.:

```
import mechanicalsoup
browser = mechanicalsoup.StatefulBrowser()
browser.open('https://www.amd.com', timeout=10)
browser.open('https://www.airfrance.fr', timeout=10)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works, I have a timeout as expected. Now, while the two examples amd.com or airfrance.fr are working websites, why does mechanicalsoup can't manage to open them ? Is there a way to scrap these sites using mechanicalsoup ? Sometimes it works. Thanks !

Comment: Probably these websites use JavaScript, for which MechanicalSoup won't help.